# Android Studio сортировка предложений (методов и переменных)

Tags: android-studio

Можно ли как то заставить предлагать методы и переменные, например по кол-ву их использования, например: набираю **r** ожидая получить **return** а оно мне предлагает **retainInstance** который я даже не разу не юзал, и так много с чем... [image: введите сюда описание изображения]